# JQuery Accordion TypeError: this.slideshow is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got an accordion that is added dynamically (using AJAX).

In Chromium (v.45.0.2454.101) everything works alright.
However, in Google Chrome and Firefox, the accordion is not created and I get this error message in the console:

```
TypeError: this.slideshow is undefined
```

My website is online. [Here](http://fcss.ukma.kiev.ua/~alosha/?a=registration) is one of the problematic pages. (accordion-reg is invisible, because it would fade in if it worked good)

Error occurs after loading and setting body of the page like this:

```
$('#BODY').html(newBody);
```

HTML of newBody is processed, script(registration.js) with $(...).accordion(...) is executed. Execution goes into depths of JQuery UI. Error occurs in **_create** function of accordion in line:

```
this.slideshow.addClass( "ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" )
        // ARIA
        .attr( "role", "tablist" );
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that JQuery files that were stored on the server somehow got corrupted. I reloaded them and now everything works.